# batch file to move files from sub dirs to root dir with overwritting files with name conflicts

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

So requesting some help, I am currently trying to sort out a mess in my google photos. I have downloaded the archive of my google photos and have a bunch of folders with files/photos in them. I am trying to write a batch file to move the files/photos from the folder to the root of this portable drive I am using for the cleanup.

So far I have this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do move "%%f" .
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:D /s /b') do rd "%%f"
```

It works the only problem I have is that potentially there could be photos with the same filename in different folders and I don't want to overwrite.

Is there any parameter I can set on the move command to block the overwrite?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I see the confirmation message now but it's not exactly what I need, I need to file to still move and just have the filename changed like adding a number

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: @DavidPostill i have created a new question here http://superuser.com/questions/1077934/move-files-in-sub-folders-to-parent-folder-avoiding-overwrite-by-changing-filena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there any parameter I can set on the move command to block the overwrite?

You can use the `/-Y` switch (Enable confirmation prompt, when overwriting files).

The following trick will answer `n`, so the move doesn't happen:

```
echo n|move /-y "%%f" .
```

Notes:

- This trick only works for a single file, no wildcards
- If a file is **not** moved your following `rd` command will fail with th following error:

  ```
  The directory is not empty.
  ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [move](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) - Move a file from one folder to another.
- [rd](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) - Delete folder(s).

Comment: thanks, is there any way to still make the move but slightly change the filename ... like add a number before the extension

Comment: Yes. But that requires a lot more work.