# Move files in sub folders to parent folder avoiding overwrite by changing filename

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

In continuation of the question I asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1077913/batch-file-to-move-files-from-sub-dirs-to-root-dir-with-overwritting-files-with):

I would like to ask how it would be possible to still do the move, but still avoiding the overwrite by changing the filename. Like for example adding a suffix to the filename with an incremental number.

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928864/batch-file-that-keeps-both-files-when-a-name-conflict-occurs-and-renames-file) might be of help but I am not sure how to integrate with batch file I did so far.

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
del /S *.json
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do call :SUB_COPY "%%f" "I:\"
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:D /s /b') do rd "%%f"
exit /B


:SUB_COPY source_item target_dir
if not "%~3"=="" (
    >&2 echo ERROR: too many arguments!
)
set "SOURCE=%~f1"
if not defined SOURCE (
    >&2 echo ERROR: missing argument!
    exit /B 1
) else if not exist "%SOURCE%" (
    >&2 echo ERROR: source not found!
    exit /B 1
)
set "TARGET=%~f2"
if not defined TARGET set "TARGET=."

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    2^> nul xcopy /L /S /E /Y /I "%SOURCE%" "%TEMP%\" ^| findstr /V /R "^[0-9]"
') do (
    > con echo "%%~I"
    call :SUB_DO "%%~I" "%TARGET%"
)
exit /B

:SUB_DO source_file target_dir
set "SUFFIX="
:CHECK
if exist "%~f2\%~n1%SUFFIX%%~x1" (
    set /A SUFFIX-=1
) else (
    2> nul md "%~f2"
    > nul 2>&1 copy /B "%~f1" "%~f2\%~n1%SUFFIX%%~x1" && (
        echo INFO: copied "%~nx1" as "%~n1%SUFFIX%%~x1".
    ) || (
        >&2 echo ERROR: copying of "%~nx1" failed!
        exit /B 1
    )
    exit /B
)
goto :CHECK
```

it's still flawed when I run it I get into some sort of loop and start creating files with weird filenames.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have got to this point now but it's still flawed when I run it I get into some sort of loop and start creating files with weird filenames. .. http://pastebin.com/BFBaZq7g

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)